# Eigenvalues and Frobenius Norm of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been working on this problem, and I think that I almost have the solution, but I'm not quite there.

Suppose that $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1... \lambda_n$. Show that $\sqrt{\sum _{j=1}^{n} \left | {\lambda_j} \right | } \leq \left \| A \right \|_F$.

I tried using the Schur decomposition of $A$ and got that $\left \| A \right \|_F = \sqrt{TT^*}$, but I'm not sure how to relate this back to eigenvalues and where the inequality comes from.

Comment: The left hand side is not homogeneous. Multiply any matrix by $g$. By taking $g$ small enough you can always find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You can only show that

$$\sqrt{\sum _{j=1}^{n} \left | {\lambda_j} \right |^2 } \leq \left \| A \right \|_F$$

Note that $\left \| A \right \|_F = \sqrt{\sum_{ij} |a_{ij}|^2}$. Hence, by the Schur decomposition you can obtain the result.

Also, your proposition is not correct. A counter example: $A = \operatorname{diag} \{0.8, 0.9\}$.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that on the left is not the absolute value of the sum? Otherwise, what is the interpretation when all eigenvalues are negative?

In case it is the absolute value of the sum, here's a quick idea when everything's real: the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace of A. So (sum of eigenvalues)$^2$ = (trace of A)$^2\le$ (trace of $A^TA$). Taking square roots of both sides, we find |sum of eigenvalues|$\le\|A\|_F.$

Comment: You are correct - I missed the absolute value sign.

Comment: Could you explain why $tr(A)^2 \leq tr(A^TA)$ ?

Comment: I take it all back :). For the $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix with 1 and 10 on the diagonal the relationship is not true. So I'll have to think a little more about this.